# Vba Adodb query error

Tags: sql, excel, adodb, vba

I have excel sheet like this

```
RETAIL_SKU  STUDIO_NAME REGION  MERCHANT    SOURCE_TYPE RETOUCH_LEVEL   

CCCF9X55FI  CCRY1B          EU  Buy VIP     Studio       9   
CCCHB1Z8EE  PCCL3B          NA  Buy VIP     Studio       9   
CCCFECJQ1I  LEJ1A           EU  Buy VIP     Studio       9   
CCCH296DN0  CCRY1B          EU  Buy VIP     Studio       9   
CCCEQR38LQ  PCCL3B          NA  Buy VIP     Studio       9   
CCCHSC2X0I  PCCL3B          NA  Buy VIP     Studio       9   
CCCA0IY4OU  BV-DE-RETAIL    EU  Buy VIP     Vendor       9   
CCCGX64C68  PCCL3B          NA  Buy VIP     Studio       9   
CCCG7U7W4O  CCRY1B          EU  Buy VIP     Studio       9
```

Looking result like this

```
STUDIO_NAME REGION
CCRY1B            3
PCCL3B            4
LEJ1A             1
BV-DE-RETAIL      1
```

i'm trying to achieve this though Ado-db .But i havent found any solution so far.

This is my below code which i have tried

```
str = "SELECT STUDIO_NAME,COUNT(*) RETAIL_SKU FROM [Sheet7$] WHERE MERCHANT='Buy VIP' AND RETOUCH_LEVEL=9 GROUP BY STUDIO_NAME"
rsEx.Open str, ConEx, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic ' this is where i'm getting error
```

i getting the below error

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL statement should be like this

`SELECT STUDIO_NAME,COUNT(*) AS REGION FROM [Sheet7$] WHERE MERCHANT='Buy VIP' AND RETOUCH_LEVEL=9 GROUP BY STUDIO_NAME`